# jQuery get ID from $el

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey all I am after the ID of a element and **this** is all I have to work with in order to get it.

```
_open: function() {
    toolTip(false);
    theLimit = this.options.limit;
    console.log('debug: ', $(this)[0]);

    if (this.options.showDropdown !== false) {
        if (tagLimit != this.options.limit) {
            this.open();
        } else {
            toolTip(true);
        }
    }
},
```

The JS above is trying to get the **ID** from the **$(this)[0]**.

I've tried

> $(this)[0].el.attr('id')
>
> $(this)[0].el.attr('id')
>
> $(this)[0].attr('id')
>
> $(this).attr('id')
>
> this.attr('id')

but those do not produce anything but **undefined** when it should show **bomtags**.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The pictures above show the current output of **$(this)[0]**.

How can I get that **id** value?

Comment: What about `this.$el[0].id`?

Comment: Boom. that was it @trincot. Please make that comment an official answer please so credit can be given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the debug information it should be:

```
this.$el[0].id
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks trincot!

Comment: NB: `this.$el.attr('id')` might also work (if `$el` is a jQuery object).